# How do I change the Audio tag in HTML5 to add custom controls?

Tags: html

So in HTML5 Audio Tag, by adding the "control" attribute, you get some pre-defined controls.  How do I add and remove from this?

More specifically, I would like to remove the current seek time.  And add a play speed button.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have native controls or you do not.

If you want to have *some* controls but not all the native controls, then you must implement them yourself using the [JavaScript APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-elements).

Comment: That's very unfortunate